# Emscripten throws exception for unresolved mcount symbol

Tags: c, build, profiling, emscripten

Trying to get emscripten to build an old C project. It builds, but throws a warning:

`warning: unresolved symbol: mcount`

Which is weird, because that's not something in my code, but it shows up in the .js file all over the place and in weird places too. Can't tell what it's doing.

Trying to run it in a browser throws an exception from the missing function.

`uncaught exception: abort(-1) at jsStackTrace@file: ...`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the `-pg` gcc flag I was previously calling so I could profile it.

`emcc main.c display.o azure.o -o main.html -lm  -s USE_SDL=2 -s USE_SDL_TTF=2 -g -Wall  -pg -O2 -Wl,-rpath,.`

It inserts it's own _mcount functions everywhere to see how long parts take.

Remove it and remember next time you profile something to not let that get into the commit.

Comment: I hate that feeling when you feel like you've been here before but you can't remember the way.